# Cannot See Workflows while Running Temporal on AWS ECS with AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-elasticsearch, temporal-workflow

I deployed Temporal along with Temporal Web on AWS ECS. I replicated the configuration using this Docker Compose file: https://github.com/temporalio/docker-compose/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

I used this configuration file: https://github.com/temporalio/docker-compose/blob/main/dynamicconfig/development_es.yaml

For Elasticsearch, I used a single node password enabled AWS Elasticsearch domain having ES v7.10.

For Postgres, I used a single instance password enabled AWS RDS database having Postgres v13.3.

My task definition for Temporal is as follows:

```
{
    "ipcMode": null,
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/dev-ecs-task-execution-role",
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "dnsSearchDomains": null,
        "environmentFiles": null,
        "logConfiguration": {
          "logDriver": "awslogs",
          "secretOptions": null,
          "options": {
            "awslogs-group": "awslogs-dev",
            "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
            "awslogs-create-group": "true",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-temporal"
          }
        },
        "entryPoint": [],
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 7233,
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "containerPort": 7233
          }
        ],
        "command": [],
        "linuxParameters": null,
        "cpu": 32,
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "DB",
            "value": "postgresql"
          },
          {
            "name": "DB_PORT",
            "value": "5432"
          },
          {
            "name": "DYNAMIC_CONFIG_FILE_PATH",
            "value": "/temporal/development_es.yaml"
          },
          {
            "name": "ENABLE_ES",
            "value": "true"
          },
          {
            "name": "ES_PORT",
            "value": "443"
          },
          {
            "name": "ES_SCHEME",
            "value": "https"
          },
          {
            "name": "ES_VERSION",
            "value": "v7"
          },
          {
            "name": "LOG_LEVEL",
            "value": "info"
          },
          {
            "name": "SERVICES",
            "value": "history,matching,frontend,worker"
          }
        ],
        "resourceRequirements": null,
        "ulimits": [],
        "dnsServers": null,
        "mountPoints": [
          {
            "readOnly": true,
            "containerPath": "/temporal",
            "sourceVolume": "configVolume"
          }
        ],
        "workingDirectory": null,
        "secrets": [
          {
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:999999999999:parameter/docker/dev/temporal_POSTGRES_USERNAME",
            "name": "POSTGRES_USER"
          },
          {
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:999999999999:parameter/docker/dev/temporal_POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
            "name": "POSTGRES_PWD"
          },
          {
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:999999999999:parameter/docker/dev/temporal_POSTGRES_HOST",
            "name": "POSTGRES_SEEDS"
          },
          {
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:999999999999:parameter/docker/dev/temporal_ES_HOST",
            "name": "ES_SEEDS"
          },
          {
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:999999999999:parameter/docker/dev/temporal_ES_USERNAME",
            "name": "ES_USER"
          },
          {
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:999999999999:parameter/docker/dev/temporal_ES_PASSWORD",
            "name": "ES_PWD"
          }
        ],
        "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
        "memory": 256,
        "memoryReservation": 128,
        "volumesFrom": [],
        "stopTimeout": 60,
        "image": "temporalio/auto-setup:1.15.0",
        "startTimeout": null,
        "firelensConfiguration": null,
        "dependsOn": null,
        "disableNetworking": null,
        "interactive": null,
        "healthCheck": null,
        "essential": true,
        "links": null,
        "hostname": null,
        "extraHosts": null,
        "pseudoTerminal": null,
        "user": null,
        "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
        "dockerLabels": null,
        "systemControls": null,
        "privileged": null,
        "name": "temporal"
      }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "memory": null,
    "taskRoleArn": null,
    "compatibilities": [
      "EC2"
    ],
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:999999999999:task-definition/temporal-dev:36",
    "family": "temporal-dev",
    "requiresAttributes": [
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "ecs.capability.efsAuth"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "ecs.capability.efs"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "ecs.capability.container-ordering"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.25"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "ecs.capability.secrets.ssm.environment-variables"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
      },
      {
        "targetId": null,
        "targetType": null,
        "value": null,
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
      }
    ],
    "pidMode": null,
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
      "EC2"
    ],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "runtimePlatform": null,
    "cpu": null,
    "revision": 36,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "inferenceAccelerators": null,
    "proxyConfiguration": null,
    "volumes": [
      {
        "fsxWindowsFileServerVolumeConfiguration": null,
        "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
          "transitEncryptionPort": null,
          "fileSystemId": "fs-99999999",
          "authorizationConfig": null,
          "transitEncryption": null,
          "rootDirectory": "temporal"
        },
        "name": "configVolume",
        "host": null,
        "dockerVolumeConfiguration": null
      }
    ]
}
```

My task definition for Temporal Web is as follows:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/dev-ecs-task-execution-role",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "awslogs-dev",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
          "awslogs-create-group": "true",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-temporal-web"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8088,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8088
        }
      ],
      "command": [],
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 32,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "TEMPORAL_GRPC_ENDPOINT",
          "value": "temporal.dev-local:7233"
        },
        {
          "name": "TEMPORAL_PERMIT_WRITE_API",
          "value": "true"
        }
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": [],
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": [],
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": 256,
      "memoryReservation": 128,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": 60,
      "image": "temporalio/web:1.13.0",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "temporal-web"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": null,
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:999999999999:task-definition/temporal-web-dev:7",
  "family": "temporal-web-dev",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.container-ordering"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "runtimePlatform": null,
  "cpu": null,
  "revision": 7,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

I'm able to run those 2 containers successfully and temporal connects to and writes data on Postgres and Elasticsearch successfully.

The issue is, I'm not able to see any workflows on the Temporal Web UI neither in my created namespace nor under the default namespace but I can see data on Elasticsearch.

I'm not able to find any error logs, I only see info logs under AWS CloudWatch for both Temporal and Temporal Web UI.

**What did I miss? What's the actual issue? Is there any tutorial or guide available to make it work on AWS ECS with AWS RDS Postgres and AWS Elasticsearch using dynamic configuration?**

*Note: When I run it locally using docker-compose, it works.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the `temporal-system` namespace here and I was able to see the workflows: `https://temporal-dev.example.com/namespaces/temporal-system/workflows?range=last-30-days&status=ALL`

I can also see workflows in our namespaces.

I did the following things:

- I enabled authentication (username and password) on Elasticsearch for successful connectivity.
- I deleted the temporal index from Elasticsearch.
- I upgraded the temporal version to v1.15.0 by using the following image: `temporalio/auto-setup:1.15.0`

  - It was 1.13.1 before.
- I deleted the temporal databases from Postgres.
- I restarted the temporal ECS services and the services that create namespaces.

**It worked.**

Comment: Thanks. We had a similar (or perhaps same) issue where workflows disappeared from the temporal web ui as well as not being visible when running `tctl workflow listall`. We disabled elasticsearch, which seems to have worked around the issue.

Comment: @honeyp0t yes, that also works but if we need Elasticsearch, disabling it is not an option.